# Spreadsheet Sorting Function

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I want to only grab certain values from a column and put them in another column. Here is a graphic of what we would want the output to be. I am using Google Sheets.

Example of what I am trying to do:

[image]

Help of any kind would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is achieved with the [`filter`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) formula. If in D2 you have

=filter(B2:B, A2:A = "A")

that column will contain the entries from column B where the corresponding column A entry is "A". Similarly for others.

Answer (score 0):

Use query. In D2, E2, F2 put:

```
=query(A2:B,"select B where B contains 'A'")

=query(A2:B,"select B where B contains 'B'")

=query(A2:B,"select B where B contains 'C'")
```